# Files with whitespaces in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to run the command `myconversion 'my input file.xlsx' 'my output file.xlsx'` in a snakefile. I tried

```
input:
    "my input file.xlsx"
output:
    "my output file.xlsx"
shell:
    "myconversion {input:q} {output:q}"
```

However, this does not work. I get the Python error

```
Error: Invalid value for "infile": Path "'my" does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Snakemake allows use of spaces in filenames. I tested your code and it works fine (snakemake v4.8.0 and macOS Sierra). What OS and snakemake version are you using? Out of curiosity, what does `:q` refer to in shell command?

Comment: `:q` automatically puts quotes around the input and output filenames (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html). I use Windows 10 and snakemake 5.1.5.

Comment: Interesting. Any clue why it didn't work when it sounds like it should have?

Comment: There usually are workarounds for these kind of problems, but I would very strongly advise you against using spaces in file names in general, if you are going to perform some kind of automated tasks. If you are not responsible for the file creation, ask your collaborators to provide files without spaces in their names: it can only benefit the both of you in the long run.

Comment: I know, and I usually avoid that. @JeeYem No, no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with your shell command and not snakemake. For CLI tools, you need to specify your filenames within quotes.

```
rule asd:
    input:
        "my input file.xlsx"
    output:
        "my output file.xlsx"
    shell:
        'cat "{input}" "{output}"'
```

Comment: Alternatively you can tell snakemake to quote the wildcard eg: `{input:q}`